# Casting from one templated container to another

Tags: c++, casting, c++-cx

I'm currently writing WinRT code, but I imagine this question applies to all C++. Upon user interaction, the framework calls one of my functions passing in a vector with generic Object^ pointers (very similar to void* for you non-WinRT folks). I already know what type of objects are in the vector and I'd like to cast the vector to that object type.

Example:

```
MyClass::SomeFunction(Vector<Object^>^ myList) {
    // Warning: The following line doesn't work!!
    Vector<SpecificType^>^ myTypedList = static_cast<Vector<SpecificType^>^>(myList);

    // Here, I go on to interact with the templated vector.
    ...
}
```

The compiler doesn't allow me to use static_cast. safe_cast throws an exception. dynamic_cast doesn't throw an exception, but returns a null pointer.

Is there a way I can cast this thing, or do I literally have to create a new vector and copy all the members over (casting each from Object^ to SpecificType^ on insertion)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast `Vector<Object^>` to any other `Vector<>` because there is no inheritance involved between them. The only thing that you can do is cast each element into the right class. So, if you want a `Vector<SpecificType^>` you do indeed need to create it anew. Not that it is too hard:

```
Vector<SpecificType^> specificList;
for (Object^ p : myList)
  specificList.push_back(static_cast<SpecificType^>(p));
```

Comment: Lame. I guess that explains why I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: More specifically, unlike C#, C++/CX does not support generic type covariance/contravariance.  `Vector<T>` and `Vector<U>` are unrelated types, regardless of the relationship between `T` and `U`.

Comment: @AndyRich In this case covariance/contravariance would not help you, because a vector is typically a read/write structure. But in other templates what you say would work in C#, indeed.